# AWK - how to selectively modify txt file

Tags: awk

I would like to print particular 2nd field (that matches regex) of each record

```
awk '$2 ~ /regex1/'
```

BUT, ONLY specific records, that are between regex2 and regex3

```
awk '/regex2/,/regex3/'
```

other records, that are not between regex2 and regex3 shall be printed normally (all fields)

any ideas, how to put it together?

quick sample of input and output:

input

```
parrot   milana  3 ukraine
dog      husky   1 poland
cat      husky   5 france
elephant malamut 5 belgium
bird     husky   5 turkey
```

output: (show me

```
parrot   milana  3 ukraine
dog      husky   1 poland
         husky            
elephant malamut 5 belgium    
bird     husky   5 turkey
```

1. Show entire input but:
2. Between /dog/ and /elephant/ (show these records unchanged) show only 2nd field, which  match regex /husky/

I hope this is usefull...

Comment: can you please illustrate your need with sample input data, and required output data. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
awk '/regex2/,/regex3/'
```

is shorthand for

```
awk '/regex2/{f=1} f; /regex3/{f=0}'
```

The shorthand version IMHO should NEVER be used as it's brevity isn't worth the difficulty it introduces when you try to build on it with other criteria, e.g. not printing the start line and/or not printing  the end line and/or introducing other REs to match within the range as you're doing now.

Given that, you're starting with this script:

```
awk '/dog/{f=1} f; /elephant/{f=0}'
```

and you want to only print the lines where you find "husky" so it's the simple, obvious tweak:

```
awk '/dog/{f=1} f && /husky/; /elephant/{f=0}'
```

EDIT: in response to changed requirements, and using a tab-separated file:

```
$ cat file
parrot  milana  3       ukraine
dog     husky   1       poland
cat     husky   5       france
elephant        malamut 5       belgium
bird    husky   5       turkey

$ awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
/elephant/ {f=0}
{
   if (f) {
      if ($2 == "husky") {
         print "", $2
      }
   }
   else {
      print
   }
}
/dog/      {f=1}
' file
parrot  milana  3       ukraine
dog     husky   1       poland
        husky
elephant        malamut 5       belgium
bird    husky   5       turkey
```

You can write it more briefly:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
/elephant/ {f=0}
f && /husky/ { print "", $2 }
!f
/dog/      {f=1}
' file
parrot  milana  3       ukraine
dog     husky   1       poland
        husky
elephant        malamut 5       belgium
bird    husky   5       turkey
```

but I think the if-else syntax is clearest and easiest to modify for newcomers to awk. If you want different output formatting, look up "printf" in the manual.

Comment: Ed, that helps me a lot, but this is almost what I need, how to modyfy output, so that dog, and elephant records are printed in output (all fields) and cat record will be shown (but only 2nd field) btw: any links for good awk tutorials?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question, please update your posted question to show what output you're looking for. To learn awk, buy the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins and lurk in netnews at comp.lang.awk where all the awk experts hang out. You can learn a lot by reading their responses to questions. You could also poke around at http://awk.info/ but there's some things posted there that are less than ideal applications for awk so treat them with a grain of salt.

Comment: I've just edited my question, I hope it is clearly enough. Thanks for literature recommendation!

Comment: What do you want to do with records between dog and elephant that do NOT contain husky? Update your sample input/output to show that too.

Comment: those records, between dog and elephant, which 2nd field is NOT husky  - shall be ommited

Answer (score 1):

infile:

```
$ cat input

parrot   milana  3 ukraine
dog      husky   1 poland
cat      husky   5 france
elephant malamut 5 belgium
bird     husky   5 turkey
```

command:

```
$ awk '/dog/{m=1} $2 ~ /husky/ && m{print $2} !m{print} /elephant/{m=0}' input

parrot   milana  3 ukraine
husky
husky
bird     husky   5 turkey
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ambiguities with your question, but this should do it:

```
awk '/regex2/ {inside=1}
     /regex3/ {inside=0}
     $2 ~ /regex1/ && inside {print $2}
     !inside {print}' input_file
```